# Is there a snapin in mmc for particular folders on the file system?

Tags: windows, mmc

I am using Windows and regularly open a number of folders in Windows Explorer - such as locations of log files and export folders used by our applications. These folders may be on a network share or local.

Part of the role also requires monitoring the Task Scheduler for remote machines - which is where an mmc snap-in is very useful.

Is there a snap-in available which you can set a specific list of folders for easy access? The snap-in can be saved and shared with multiple users.

e.g I would like to open the following in one MMC Window;

Task Scheduler > on REMOTESERVER01

Task Scheduler > on REMOTESERVER02

Certificate Manager > on REMOTESERVER01

d$\Application Logs > on REMOTESERVER03

d$\Exports > on REMOTESERVER03

etc.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, yes: you can add "Link to Web Address" as a snap-in and write the path to your share `\\server\d$\Exports`.

It's intended for web pages, but it can browse a folder as well.

[image: Link to Web Address snap-in]

Comment: This is wonderful! Is it possible to add this using different credentials for the different shares?

Comment: Not in the .msc file. However it will behave in the same way as if you access it from the file explorer (it will ask your credential when connecting, if you don't have access to the share)

Comment: Thanks again. That's the behaviour I've seen. I guess the solution is to run mmc with the necessary credentials. This is much less of a hastle than having to open individual folders all the time!

Comment: You can use the Credential Manager if you want Windows to remember your credentials. (Just search for Credential Manager from the start menu and add Windows Credentials for your servers)